# C++ Dynamic Array of Structures User Input

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn C++ on my own using Stephen Prata's "C++ Primer Plus 6th Edition. One of the chapter 5 exercises asks me to design a dynamic structure holding name and year of a number of cars. All this information is to be input by the user.
My questions are:

1) Can I use a string object instead of an array of char in the structure? If so, could you tell me how?

2) How can I enable the user to input a name that consists of more than one word? I've been trying to use get(), getline() etc. but I just can't make it work.

3) I know it is a simple programme but in what way could the code be improved?

Thank you in advance.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const int ArSize = 20;

struct automobile
{
    char name[ArSize];
    int year;
};

int main()
{
cout << "How many cars do you wish to catalogue?\n";
int number;
cin >> number;

automobile * car = new automobile[number];
int n = 0;

while (n < number)
{
    cout << "Car #" << n+1 << ":\n";
    cout << "Please enter the make: ";
    cin >> car[n].name; cout << endl;

    cout << "Please enter the year: ";
    cin >> car[n].year; cout << endl;
    n++;
}

    cout << "Here is your collection:\n";

int m = 0;
while (m < number)
{
    cout << car[m].year << " " << car[m].name << endl;
    m++;
}
delete [] car;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. You probably can use it, but most likely it will a another lesson on the whole STD/STL stuff. 2. Why do you need to input more than one word? And why the current code does not able to do that? 3. If it is simple - don't improve it. You will make it wrong.

Comment: As for question #3, In this case, While loops are not really appropriate. Use For loops instead.  For loops are traditionally used for incrementing a variable every iteration. A while would be better if you were using a boolean flag or a conditional statement that wasn't incremented every loop. Also, be sure to indent any encapsulated lines of code for readability. Everything within int main(){ ...} should be indented.Lastly, As a new programmer i would suggest learning the difference between endl and "\n" sense you seem to be using them interchangeably but they arent exactly the same thing

Comment: One last note! Stay away from generic variable names like "number". This is a bad habit to get in. Name it something like "numCars" for the number of cars. Also, your "car" variable is a little generic as well but for this small example it'll probably work. However, since it is a list i would suggest changing it to plural since it is a list of cars not just one car. This is called self documenting code. Good habit to get into.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Can I use a string object instead of an array of char in the structure? If so, could you tell me how?

Yes, simply provide a member variable of type `std::string`:

```
struct automobile
{
    std::string name;
    int year;
};
```

> 2) How can I enable the user to input a name that consists of more than one word? I've been trying to use get(), getline() etc. but I just can't make it work.

Use [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
cout << "Please enter the make: ";
std::getline(std::cin,car[n].name); cout << endl;
```

> 3) I know it is a simple programme but in what way could the code be improved?

Such questions are better asked at [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), as soon you have working code. For Stack Overflow this often simply renders as *too broad*.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. 
I've tried using 
   `std::getline(std::cin,car[n].name); cout << endl;` 
but I get the following error:
error: no matching function for call to 'getline(std::istream&, char [20])'|

Comment: @KonradBjörnthorne That's why I said you should use `std::string name;` not `char name[ArSize];`.